# Can the guide template language be used with content in a microsite?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, gtl

Can the guide template language be used with content in a microsite? If it can then please describe change required to following to allow it to display same as email content.

```
<script runat=server> var Json = '{"foo": "bar"}';
</script>

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 20}}
    {{.data}}
     { "target" : "Json" }
    {{/data}}
foo: {{foo}}
{{/datasource}}
```

When above previewed using:

- email (guided send text) - display is `foo: bar`.
- microsite (preview using subscribers data) - display when clicking on `generate preview` is nothing.

Comment: We haven't been able to get GTL to work on SFMC Landing Pages or Microsites.  It may work in CloudPages.  Perhaps one of the SFMC folks can weigh in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliot Harper found a solution that will allow Guide Template Language to operate as intended within Microsites, CloudPages, and Landing Pages.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/131334/34199

From what I understand, the delimiters were changed to support client-side rendering for these sites using MustacheJS which uses the same delimiters. By switching back using the %%{={{ }}=}%%, Guide Template Language functions as documented.