# GTL in cloudpages: #with

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, gtl

If I have this json:

```
{
    "name":"Tania",
    "invoice":{
      "city":"BCN",
      "zip_code":"1005",
      "amount":"56.13",
      "datetime":"05/09/2017",
      "address":"Calle",
      "name":"Tania  ",
      "invoice_code":"PF2017-259224",
      "email":"ta@gmail.com"
   }
}
```

How could I get properties of invoice element?

I'm doing this in a cloudpage

```
%%{={{ }}=}%%

{{.dataobject JSONVar type=variable source=@json}}
    {{.data}}
        { "target" : "@json" }
    {{/data}}
{{/dataobject}}

{{#jsonvar}}
    Order name: {{ name }}

    {{#with invoice}}
        {{ email }}<br>
        {{ name }} <br>
        {{ address }} {{ zip_code }}  {{ city }}<br>
        Factura nº #<strong>{{ invoice_code }}</strong><br>
    {{/with}}

{{/jsonvar}}
```

But it fails in `#with`... when I remove that lines #with block it returns `Order name: Tania`, but I can't get sub-object invoice and its properties

EDIT: If I do only this: it doesn't fails but It does not print the data.

```
{{ JSONVar.invoice.email }}<br>
{{ JSONVar.invoice.name }} <br>
{{ JSONVar.invoice.address }} {{ JSONVar.invoice.zip_code }} {{ JSONVar.invoice.city }}<br>
Factura nº #<strong>{{ JSONVar.invoice.invoice_code }}</strong><br>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your situation I would try using the `{{datasource}}` within GTL. Please note in mind that documentation in GTL is not widely accurate, for example around the use of Block In helpers where `{{@index}}`, `{{@first}}` and others aren't functional. However if you have a simple structured JSON data then GTL is the best solution as it saves the time from using the SSJS.

Also if you notice in the code below I have used the `datasource` tag which uses a `datasource` defined inline as part of the template.

Please try the code below which works from my end:

```
%%{={{ }}=}%%

{{.datasource JSONVar source=@json type=variable}}
    {{.data}}
        { "target" : "@json" }
    {{/data}}

    Order name: {{ name }}

    {{.datasource invoice source=@json type=nested}}
        {{.data}}
          { "target" : "JSONVar.invoice" }
        {{/data}}

        {{ email }}<br>
        {{ name }} <br>
        {{ address }} {{ zip_code }}  {{ city }}<br>
        Factura nº #<strong>{{ invoice_code }}</strong><br>
    {{/datasource}}
{{/datasource}}
```

Comment: Your code works! Thank you! But #each and #with still give me an error How can loop through my json?

Comment: I did this work perfectly... thanks for your answer, it inspired me for getting my goal.

Comment: no worries. glad i could help. You can only use #each with {{dataobject}} in the arrays in json.

Comment: Can't wait to try this out, but I'm wondering what `%%{={{ }}=}%%` at the top of the script is meant to do. I've never seen this artefact.

Comment: Ah, found the answer to my question in the comment above: it's a method to set delimiters so that GTL may be used in CloudPages: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129057/guide-template-language-blocks-displayed-in-cloudpages/131334#131334